# How to write to a json file in flutter? Whats wrong with the code below?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

List<Widget> listWidget = [];
List<FileSystemEntity> listDirectories = [];
TextEditingController control = TextEditingController();

main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(),
           body: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                JsonHelper jsonhelper = JsonHelper(
                  body: control.text, // I have created a textField for this but not mentioning it
                  title: "Hello",
                );
                return FutureBuilder(
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      print(snapshot.data);
                      return Text("Done");
                    } else {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  },
                  future: jsonhelper.jrite(),
                );
              },
              child: Text("CREATE"),
            
);

class JsonHelper {
  String title;
  String body;

  JsonHelper({this.title, this.body});

  jrite() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File jsonfile = new File(join(directory.path, "$title.json")).create(recursive = true);
    Map contents = {"title": title, "body": body};
    File writtenfile = await jsonfile.writeAsString(jsonEncode(contents));
    return jsonDecode(await writtenfile.readAsString());
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to create a json file in the directory as shown above and return the contents of the file (or print it out), How can I get the code above to do the job for me. PLEASE HELP !!!!

I have created a button as shown above, I expect: When I press the button the snapshot.data gets printed, also gets written to a .json file. But it does nothing, literally nothing. No errrors, Doesn't print anything.

Comment: what do you have problems with?

Comment: The Thing is that it is not doing anything. Seems a little ambiguos but still. When I create the JsonHelper object, assign title & body and call object.jrite();  method, it doesn't do anything, literally nothing. The Problem is not with futureBuilder, but the above code is not working as I expect but why?

Comment: it does not return anything?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Oh, thanks. Here you are, sorry, I am new to StackOverflow.

Comment: @pskink Yes, it doesn't return, and even doesn't print anything and even doesn't write anything to a file, as I expect. :-(

Comment: so it seems it is not even called

Comment: @pskink future: jsonhelper.jrite(), Here in Futurebuilder. Doesn't this store the returned value in the snapshot?

Comment: You return the FutureBuilder from your onPressed method. What is that supposed to do? It needs to be in your widget tree. You have to have state management in your screen, you cannot just return a widget from a method and expect it to magically work.

Comment: @nvoigt Thanks. My Bad. It worked when I just made onPressed () async {} and did the same thing (without futurebuilder) with await. Thanks.